# How Can I use a kotlin expression in a thymeleaf expression th:each?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, thymeleaf

I am using a template but I can't manage to apply this Kotlin function:

```
<th:block th:each="foo: ${bar.flatMap {it.foos} }">
<...>
</th:block>
```

1. Is that even possible to use flatMap here?
2. Can I have an alternative to that in Thymeleaf?